# Input Validation Loop

Tags: java, validation, input

So my program allows a user to input a string then remove all occurrences of a character. If the character doesn't exist in the string then it should print an error message. Right now, I've created a loop to check each character in the string to create the new string without the character. I'm not sure how to create an input validation loop without printing an error message for each character that doesn't match the character the user wants to remove. I hope this makes sense!

Here is a portion of my code:

```
//REMOVE LOOP
System.out.println("Enter the character to remove");
String oldChar = keyboard.nextLine();

while ( indexEnd <= string.length() ) {
    String substring = string.substring(indexStart, indexEnd);
    indexStart++;
    indexEnd++;

}

    while ( substring.equals(oldChar) ) {
         substring = string.substring(0, indexStart-1);
         string = substring + string.substring(indexEnd - 1);
         indexStart=0;
         indexend=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest just using one of the String methods (str.replace(c, "")). That is, unless this is a homework assignment in which you have to do it with a loop.

Comment: Please add the stacktrace and code. You may also have a look at [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve the question. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1):

Add a guard clause (a check) at the beginning.

It's best to avoid while loops and write something more readable.

```
public String removeCharacter(String text, String character) {
    if(!text.contains(character)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Character " + character + " not found in text " + text);
    } else {
        return text.replace(character, "");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Swifter's answer is great and more readable, here's another alternative:

Since we're just removing characters, we know that the character wasn't found if the resulting length stays the same.

```
public String remove(String text, String character) {
    // save the original length because we are going to use it later
    var origLength = text.length();

    text = text.replace(character, "");

    // check new length against original length
    // - if they are the same, then 'character' wasn't found

    if(origLength == text.length()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Character " + character + " not found.");
    }

    return text;
}
```

Technically this is more performant since there's just one pass through the string (although in reality this is negligible).